# how to redirect the output of 2 files to a 3rd file in unix

Tags: unix

In Unix,  I came across the following interview questions.

how to redirect the output of two files to a third file?
what is kill command? options that can be given? what is the purpose of using -9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. cat file1 file2 > file3
2. kill stops a running processes
3. -9 is used to send a signal to the running process so that it stops in a certain manner.
   for example (think of it as forcing the stop)
   kill -9 myhangingprocess

For more info
man cat
man kill

Comment: You missed the most important things about -9. It's the `KILL` signal: cannot be trapped, the process will be shot down without the possibility of graceful exit and clean up